# Interface implementation syntax options in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, syntax, interface

Ok, this is a very basic question but I just ran into it. Consider the following class:

```
public class WindowComparer: IComparer, Generic.IComparer<Window> { }
```

Scenario 1: The way I would normally declare it.

```
public int Compare (object x, object y)
{
    return (this.Compare((Window) x, (Window) y));
}

public int Compare (Window x, Window y) {...}
```

Scenario 2: The way MSDN documentation normally declares it.

```
int Collections.IComparer.Compare (object x, object y)
{
    // [this.Compare] is not recognized. How to access this?
    return (this.Compare((Window) x, (Window) y));
}

int Generic.IComparer<Window>.Compare (Window x, Window y) {...}
```

However, when trying scenario 2, intellisense loses the Compare method and the compiler raises an error saying that the Compare method is not a member of WindowComparer. What am I missing?

Comment: Usually you don't need to manually call the Compare method. But some other data structure may do, say when you sort your collection.

Comment: [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) might be a good starting place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second Scenario are the interfaces `IComparer` and `IComparer<Window>` implemented explicitly, so that the methods are only accessible or callable when you assign your instance to a variable of type `IComparer<Window>` or `IComparer`.

```
WindowComparer comparer = new WindowComparer();

IComparer<Window> windowComparer = comparer;
// call methods of IComparer<Window> on windowComparer

IComparer normalComparer = comparer;
// call methods of IComparer on normalComparer
```

The interfaces are implemented explicitly to keep the public interface of the class clear and to hide the methods of infrastructure interfaces for comparing, equality, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of explicit declaration on interfaces. What purpose does that serve besides code clarity? Conflict resolution perhaps?

Comment: @RaheelKhan yes also, it could be that you implement mutiple interfaces that declare the same method signature. So in this case you need to implement one of the methods explicitly, cause it is not possible to define multiple methods with the same signature on a class.

Answer (score 1):

Using the second approach, the methods only work when you declare your object as an instance of one of the two interfaces:

```
WindowComparer wcOne = new WindowComparer();
Generic.IComparer<Window> wcTwo = new WindowComparer();
IComparer wcThree = new WindowComparer();
```

In this example, `wcOne` will have none of the two `Compare` methods because they are implemented explicitly. `wcTwo` will be able to use the one from `Generic.IComparer<Window>` and `wcThree` will be able to the one from `IComparer`.

Comment: They also work if the object is stored as a generic which is constrained to one of the interface types.  Note if a value type which implements an interface is passed as an interface-constrained generic, it will behave as a value type; by contrast, because interface-type storage locations are reference types, a value type which is passed as an interface type will behave as a reference type.  This behavior is most apparent with `List<T>.Enumerator`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        return ((this as IComparer<Window>).Compare((Window)x, (Window)y));
```

Comment: A response with just code and no explanation can be copied-and-pasted, but it will not be useful to future visitors with similar problems.

Comment: The OP asked for the "how," not the "why"... And this work-around will still be valid for any "future visitors with similar problems".

Comment: Knowing *how* to do something is not useful on the long run unless you know *why* it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

To call an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) on `this` instance, you will *have to* cast `this` to that interface, as in

```
return ((Generic.IComparer<Window>)this).Compare((Window)x, (Window)y);
```

By the way, are you putting your class inside the `System` namespaces, or do you have a `using` alias declaring the name `Generic`?